# DOM elements in console.log

Tags: javascript, html

What's the meaning of `node2` and `node3` below `length: 2` ? The DOM has two elements, and that's the array (`0` and `1` in this case) but what are the last two? I'm debugging a program and trying to figure this out.

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like it's a convenience map, in other words, it enables you to access the children elements by id.